# Evaluation of a certain polynomial on a matrix.

Tags: matrices

Given $A=\left[\begin{matrix}\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2i}&\dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2i}\\\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2i}&\dfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2i}\end{matrix}\right]$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Also Given$f(x)=x^2+2.$

Find $f(A)$

My approach:

A can be written as

$A=i\left[\begin{matrix}w&w^2\\w^2&w\end{matrix}\right]$ Here $1+w+w^2=0$ i.e  $w,w^2 \in {cube \space roots\space of \space \space unity }$

$\therefore \space f(A)=-((\left[\begin{matrix}w&w^2\\w^2&w\end{matrix}\right])^2-2)$

$=2-\left[\begin{matrix}-1&2\\2&-1\end{matrix}\right]$

Another approach:

$A=\left[\begin{matrix}\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2i}&\dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2i}\\\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2i}&\dfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2i}\end{matrix}\right]$

$=i\left[\begin{matrix} cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})+isin(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})&cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})-isin(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})\\-cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})+isin(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})&cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})-isin(\dfrac{2\pi}{3})\end{matrix}\right] $

Now using DeMoivres' Theorem I was thinking what to be done. Let me think...

Now the options given are:

a.  $\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$

b.  $\dfrac{3-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$

c.  $\dfrac{5-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$

d.  $(2+i\sqrt{3}) \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$

But my answer does not come close to any of the given options. Could someone selflessly help me out please!

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{3i\,}$ in an unambiguous way?

Comment: @Bernard I have changed the edit in the OP. Sorry!

Comment: Actually, $\; A=i\begin{bmatrix}-w&-w^2\\w&w^2\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for $A$ is not correct. You have 
$$
A=-i\begin{bmatrix} w&w^2\\ -w^2&-w\end{bmatrix}=-iw\begin{bmatrix} 1&w\\-w&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
A^2+2I=-w^2\begin{bmatrix} 1-w^2&0\\0&1-w^2\end{bmatrix}+2I=\begin{bmatrix} w-w^2+2&0\\0&w-w^2+2\end{bmatrix}=(2+i\sqrt 3)I,
$$
since
$$
w-w^2+2=-\frac12+\frac i2\sqrt3+\frac12+\frac i2\sqrt3+2=2+i\sqrt3
$$

Comment: Oh yes yes I took -1 common.